# Pyinstaller traceback

Tags: python

```
Traceback  (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 137, in <module>
File C:\Python26\buildSVG_Resizer\out1.pyz/encodings", line 100, in search_function
TypeError: importHook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'level'
```

The imports in my .py file are:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os, stat
import tkFileDialog
```

My script parses SVG's (xml) in a directory and then replaces values if they are out of range.  This script runs fine through the console.

I can post the whole script if that will help.

Thanks for anything.

Comment: post your search_function. where is importHook coming from?

Comment: The search_function is part of the Pyinstall code; same with codehook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`importHook` in `iu.py` (top level of pyinstaller) does accept a `level=` named argument, so the message is quite perplexing and suggests a bad installation.

What output do you get from cd'ing to pyinstaller's top directory and doing:

```
svn log -r HEAD
```

?  Should currently be

```
r685 | giovannibajo | 2009-06-30 05:19:59 -0700 (Tue, 30 Jun 2009) | 3 lines

Preliminar support for creating a bundle on Mac OSX.
Yet to be integrated into Makespec.py.
```

If you get something older, `svn up` to make sure you have the current version, and try packaging your project again (from the start, since, if you've used some defective version, there might have been incorrect intermediate files generated).

Comment: Apparently I downloaded the latest stable release (1.3) which is not the latest release.  Thanks for the tip, I am now pointed in the right direction.